# Objective c : add right to left language to Notes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uiactivityviewcontroller

in my app i want to add string(that contain right to left language text) like this to Notes:

```
                                                            :شماره کارت
                                                    xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
                                                             محمد کاظمی
```

this is my codes:

```
NSString *shareText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ :\n%@\n %@\n %@\n %@", NSLocalizedString(@"CardPan", @""), [self.card getCardNumberWithDashed], self.deposit.customerName, NSLocalizedString(self.bank.logo, @""), NSLocalizedString(@"ShareBankCard", @"")];

NSMutableArray *sharingItems = [NSMutableArray new];
    [sharingItems addObject:shareText];

    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = parent.view;
    activityController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake([Functions Dwidth]/2-15, 0, 30, 30);
    [parent presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

when opening Notes in my iPhone and checking my Note, the text saved like this:

```
:شماره کارت
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
محمد کاظمی
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way because you have an application with Farsi(RTL) and you want to use it in iPhone with the English Language. So Note or any other default app of iOS set own language according to iOS Language. Finally, there is a simple test or way you could set iPhone language on Arabic or other RTL languages and you can see your text will show completely good.